# Get innerText from previous sibling inside a map function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have html that looks like this:

```
<label contenteditable>Label</label>
<input type="text">
```

There are a number of these, chosen by the user so I can't know how many beforehand, and with each label edited through the `contenteditable` ability.

I want to add the `label` and input `value` into an object that should look something like this when all is said and done:

```
{
  name: "Charles",
  country: "Switzerland",
  birthPlace: "USA"
}
```

or whatever.

I figured I'd do this with the help of `map()`, inside of which I thought I could use `previousElementSibling` and `innerText` like so:

```
var newObj = {}
    $('input[type=text]').map(function() {
      var fieldName = $(this).previousElementSibling.innerText
      newObj[fieldName] = $(this).val()
    })
```

Sadly, though, this only returns an error saying that it:

> **Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined**

I've tried passing the `element` property through the function instead of using `this`, I've tried using `prev()` (which it says is not a function), I've tried everything I can think of but nothing works. "Funnily" enough, when I `console.dir($(this))` inside the map I can literally see the value of `previousElementSibling.innerText` (**edit:** Apparently I can't, but `console.dir(this)` can!), which is why I thought it would work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you've wrapped `this` in a jQuery object: `$(this)`. The jQuery object itself doesn't have a `previousElementSibling` method, but `this` does.

Either change your code to:

```
this.previousElementSibling.innerText;
```

Or use jQuery methods instead:

```
$(this).prev().text();
```

---

*As a side note, you can also use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.*

Comment: Didn't had the time to answer. Vote up https://api.jquery.com/prev/ here is the documentation